# What is this "Local Disk \:"

Tags: windows, windows-8

I went to defrag my computer today and noticed a volume with the name: `\\?\Volume{ccdc3bf0-88ca-4fb8-aa01-5b62b265e616}\` which had 35% fragmentation.

There's nothing like this in disk management, so I opened it up in explorer. When I did it said `Local Disk \:` in the title bar.

What is this volume? Where did it come from? And why does it have 35% fragmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "volume GUID", one of the primary ways Windows identifies volumes.

Run `mountvol` to see all volumes, and the disk letters or mountpoints assigned to them.

Comment: So is there any way to defrag this volume? I tried ***defrag \\?\Volume{ccdc3bf0-88ca-4fb8-aa01-5b62b265e616}\***, which didn't seem to work.

Comment: There was no error by the way. It said 'The operation completed successfully.' But the fragmentation is still at 35%.
Also if it matters, it's a Recovery Partition.

Comment: Sometimes it's just not possible to defragment a filesystem completely (e.g. not enough space to move the existing fragments). You can try assigning it a drive letter and try again, if you want. (It being a recovery partition explains why it didn't have any letter assigned.) Note that Windows has supported mounting volumes to paths for at least 13 years, so `defrag` and other tools like `chkdsk` *do* accept any valid name (letter, path, volume GUID) – as you say, it didn't show any error message about it, so the name is definitely not the problem.